# NodeJS Static function is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, static-methods

I made a NodeJS application which usere a static Method to do some calculation Function.
When i try to acces the Method i got the isNotAFunction Error.

Here a static class which causes the error while accessing it:

```
exports.module = class PlaceEvaluator
{
    static testMethod()
    {
        console.log("Test");
    }
}
```

Here is the Code of the file which throws the Exception while reading:

```
PositionFinder = require("./positionFinder.js");
PlaceObj = require("./placeObj.js");
PlaceEvaluator = require("./placeEvaluator.js");
fetch = require("cross-fetch");
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http").createServer(express);
const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
    cors:{
        origin: "*"
    }
});



const application = express();

application.use(express.static("public"));

PlaceEvaluator.testMethod();

io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.on("placeQuery", async ({topic, lat, long}) => {
       
        PlaceEvaluator.testMethod();  //Here is the Exception function call 
       
        //console.log("Response sent!");
    })
})

async function findPlaceObject(type, lat, long)
{
    let placeObj = await PositionFinder.FetchPosition(type, lat, long);
    return placeObj;
}

function convertToPlaceObjArr(inputObj)
{
    var outputArr = [];

    let name;
    let lat;
    let long;
    

    for(var i = 0; i < inputObj.results.length; i++)
    {
        name = inputObj.results[i].name;
        lat = inputObj.results[i].geometry.location.lat;
        long = inputObj.results[i].geometry.location.lng; 
        outputArr.push(new PlaceObj(name, lat, long));
        console.log(inputObj.results[i].name);
    }

    return outputArr;
}


http.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log("Running on Port 4000");
    // PositionFinder.FetchPosition("Pizza", "51.896359", "6.982303");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `module.exports` to export a default rather than `exports.module`.

By using `exports.module` you are exporting your class with the key of `module` so in that case you would have to do:

```js
PlaceEvaluator.module.testMethod();
```